# Letter-spacing input even

Tags: html, css, forms, letter-spacing

I am making a html form with a inputfield. If I use letters and numbers the letter-spacing is incorrect. How do I make sure that the letter-spacing is always good?

**Good:**

[image: Good]

**Bad (letter-spacing):**
[image: Bad]

```
input{
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
  background: transparent;
  height: 76px;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Avenir", sans-serif !important;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 600px;
  letter-spacing: 49px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}
```

---

```
<div class="coupon">
  <h3 class="widget-title bluetext">Coupon</h3>
  <div class="couponwrap">
    <input type="text" id="ticket-number" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false"  maxlength="8" minlength="8">
    <div class="cursor-hide"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: Use a monospaced font, or create 8 input fields.

Comment: `text-align:center`?

Comment: `text-align: center;` might be better than left aligning.

Comment: can you update your html code

Comment: Text-align: center is not a solution. I want to left start typing

Comment: Wouldn't `text-align` center break down if theres an uneven/even number of characters...? `monospace` seems the only solution as letter widths are different for each...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was stated in the comments, you should use a mono-space font like Courier. Avenir's characters (and other non-mono-spaced characters) have unique horizontal space per character.

If Avenir is absolutely necessary, you could use multiple inputs with javascript auto incrementing on input.